# Access objects parent from after_save block

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is my model:

```
class Why < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :story
  after_save :complete

  private
    def complete
      self.story.update_attributes(:completed => true)
    end
end
```

and controller code:

```
class WhiesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @whies = Why.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @whies }
    end
  end

  def show
    @why = Why.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @why }
    end
  end

  def new
    @why = Why.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @why }
    end
  end

  def create
    @story = Story.find(params[:story_id])
    @why = @story.build_why(params[:why])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @why.save
        format.html { redirect_to story_path(@why.story) }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @why, :status => :created, :location => @why }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @why.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @why = Why.find(params[:id])
    @why.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(whies_url) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end

end
```

I get an `The error occurred while evaluating nil.update_attributes` error coming from the complete after_save method. Can anyone suggest what the problem is, or a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, actually.

Try this:

```
@story = Story.find(params[:story_id])
@why = Why.new(params[:why])
@why.story = @story
```

Comment: @lulalala not sure why I said I still get the error. I'm pretty sure it worked after explicity assigning @why a story (`@why.story = @story`) before calling save...

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your `Story` class `has_one :why`?

From playing around in the console, it looks like your code works perfectly fine, **the first time I run it.** If I then do it again (using the same `@story`), I get your error.

What's happening is that when you execute `build_why`, Rails is checking to see if `@story` already has another `Why` object associated with it, and if so, it removes the association. When it removes this association, it executes the `after_save` callback on the previous story, at which point `self.story` is now `nil`. You'll see this happen in your logs before you ever call `@why.save`.

You could probably just wrap your `update_attributes` call in a `if self.story` conditional, but there may be a bigger flaw with the logic in your program.

Comment: Yes, `Story has_one :why`
There shouldn't be the situation where a story already has a why. Putting the conditional fixes the error, but i lose the desired functionality. I'm open to suggestions on how to do it a better way...